# Extract phone numbers using regex not followed or preceded by digit(s)

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract phone numbers using Regex that are not followed or preceded by a digit.

```
ogle+logo-e1396374999431.jpeg // should not match

tel:8054051124">805-405-1234 // should match
```

Here is Regex that does `SHOULD NOT HAVE DIGITS IN THE END` but it does not do `SHOULD NOT HAVE DIGITS AT BEGINNING`

```
(\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4})(?!\d)
```

Online link: https://regex101.com/r/Irshpq/1/

I also tried `(?!\d)(\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4})(?!\d)` and some other things by searching online but did not work.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Add a negative lookbehind `(?<!\d)`:

```
(\(?(?<!\d)\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4})(?!\d)
    ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gj6Cz8/1)

If you need to avoid matching the numbers with `(123)` preceded with a digit, move the lookbehind to the start of the pattern.